# Connect Android to OTG cable and PC

Tags: usb, usb-debugging, usb-host-mode

**TLDR:** I'm wondering if it's possible to connect a android device to a device(lets say usb flash drive) while staying connected to the computer.

I'm developing a app that requires a ftdi chip to be connected to my device via USB. I connected a OTG cable and everything works just fine. The problem is that I want to do some debugging(i use android studio) and i need the PC connected to the tablet at the same time.

I tried multiple ways to connect to a adapter using a otg cable and normal cable

At this point i'm wondering if it's even possible to do that.

Comment: See [How to debug in Android Studio using adb over WiFi](//stackoverflow.com/q/33726622)

Comment: Thanks for the workaround.